# How do you setup tab settings for user defined file types in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to setup Notepad++ to be able to edit a particular source-code file (***.mrc** / mIRC Scripting File). The only thing I can't figure out is how to set the tab settings to 3 spaces.

I've searched google, however, I can't seem to find how to do this. The extent of what I search brings me to the setup for a user-defined language which I've already pretty much done. Tabs are the last steps.

When I add my user-defined file type to notepad++, the extension doesn't register in the `Settings > Preferences > Language Menus` tab. >:/

Comment: I ended up changing the "Default" tab spacing to what I use the most, as most of the other files I work with are defined natively in the application.

Comment: Related question on Super User: [Changing tab size/length in a User Defined Language in Notepad++](https://superuser.com/q/1196263/302629)

Comment: @sshow should add his suggestion as an answer. This worked for me too, and is the only way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @Ameer: I added an answer now. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always edit the `langs.xml` file. It contains code like:

```
<Language name="batch" ext="bat cmd nt" commentLine="REM">
    <Keywords name="instre1">rem set if else exist errorlevel for in do break call copy chcp cd chdir choice cls country ctty date del erase dir echo exit goto loadfix loadhigh mkdir md move path pause prompt rename ren rmdir rd shift time type ver verify vol com con lpt nul defined not errorlevel cmdextversion</Keywords>
</Language>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  The option is now there, but it doesn't really enforce it.

Comment: Behavior remains default despite this adding a menu option.

Comment: Editing `langs.xml` requires a different editor and possibly admin priviliges. The file says: `<!-- The key words of the supported languages, don't touch them! -->`. Adding a `Language` element does not change the language list in v6.3.2 (2013-04-03).

Answer (score 3):

I ended up changing the "Default" tab spacing to what I use the most, and most of the other files I work with are already explicitly defined in the application.

Comment: This should be the a accepted answer. The answer by @matzahboy does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread, but I had the problem recently.

This is how you change that:

1. Open Notepad++ settings dialog. There click on `Language`.
2. On the right section where it says `Tabs` select the language.
3. Uncheck `Use default`.
4. On `Tab size` click on the blue number. In the dialog change the number to your likings and close them.
5. Check `Replace with spaces` if needed.